# Tool for pdf comparison with images to be integrated with test scripts

Tags: compare, comparison, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3, beyondcompare4

Analyzing tools for pdf comparison to compare text, images (all elements in the pdf) and that can be integrated with test scripts (for automated comparison)

I looked at **Beyond Compare**. They have command line utility that can help to trigger the comparison automatically with scripts.
However do not have a robust solution for images comparison within pdf.

Is there any feature that i am missing to enable image comparison

Answer (score 1):

Beyond Compare doesn't support comparing images in PDF files, only plain text.